# Stop re-sharper alphabetically ordering fields?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

Is seems Re-sharper is constantly alphabetically ordering my fields on code clean up, could anyone tell me how I can stop this and just leave the fields in the order they were before the code cleanup?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the way things get ordered in `Options -> c# -> File Layout`, then choose the element type, and adjust the `Sort By`

[image]

Comment: On "Sort By" I don't have a dropdown list, all I have is just an empty field that it wont let me click? Here is a screenshot example: https://i.imgur.com/CdzVtSY.png

Comment: That's a head-scratcher... The screenshot in my answer is from my PC right now... My only other suggestion is not to run the full code cleanup, just the reformat code

Comment: @spart it is a known issue in the latest ReSharper build https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-467675, will be fixed soon. Till the fix is available, you might open XAML presentation of the layout (XAML link at the top of the page), look for 'Entry DisplayName="Fields"' block and remove "Name" record from "Entry.SortBy" block.